# Android: how do I return to to top of RecyclerView after adding item?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView list of CardViews.  New CardViews are inserted at the top of the list.

If the View is currently at the bottom of the CardView list and I click my "Add" button to create a new CardView, I want the RecyclerView to then show the new CardView at the top of the list.  Currently, when the new CardView is created the RecyclerView just returns to the previous View at the bottom of the list.

I've tried many things, without any luck, including:

```
recyclerView.getLayoutManager().scrollToPosition(0); 
recyclerView.scrollToPosition(0);
linearlayoutmanager.scrollToPositionWithOffset(0,0)
```

Adapter.java

```
public void add(Contact item) {
    if (contactList.size()==0) {
        contactList.clear();
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    contactList.add(item);
    notifyItemInserted(0);
}

public void addAll(List<Contact> contactList) {
    for (Contact contact : contactList) {
        add(contact);
    }
}
```

Activity.java

```
...    
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    EmptyRecyclerView recyclerView = (EmptyRecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.list_recyclerview);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);               
    recyclerView.setEmptyView(findViewById(R.id.empty_view));
    contactListAdapter = new ContactListAdapter(this);
    contactListAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(contactListAdapter);        

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    loadData();
}

void loadData(){  
    List<Contact> contactList = new ArrayList<>();
    Cursor cursor = sqLiteDB.retrieve();
    Contact contact;

    try {
        if (cursor.getCount() > 0) { 
            cursor.moveToFirst(); 
            while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) { 
                do {
                    contact = new Contact();
                    contact.setI(cursor.getInt(0));
                    contact.setC(cursor.getInt(1));
                    contact.setT(cursor.getString(2));
                    contact.setN1(cursor.getString(3));
                    contact.setN2(cursor.getString(4));
                    contact.setD(cursor.getString(5));
                    contact.setDt(cursor.getString(6));
                    contact.setTm(cursor.getLong(7));
                    // add the item to the top of the List.
                    contactList.add(0, contact);
                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }
        }
    } finally {
        if (cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed()) {
            cursor.close();
        }
    }
    contactListAdapter.clear();
    contactListAdapter.addAll(contactList);
```

Comment: When you make the scroll?

Comment: I tried after "layoutManager".  I also tried after "setAdapter".  I also tried using the recyclerView after "NotifyItemInserted(0)'" in the add() of the Adapter.

Comment: Your `add()` method is inside recyclerview, no?

Comment: No it is in the Adapter:  "public void add(Contact item)"  See Adapter.java code above.

Answer (score 3):

do like this

```
recyclerview.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
           LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = (LinearLayoutManager) mRecyclerView.getLayoutManager();
           layoutManager.scrollToPositionWithOffset(0, 0);
        }
    });
```

if this does not work check where are you calling this and control executes this statement or not.

Comment: Ok I will try it.

Comment: App crashed with NullPointerException.  It didn't like the line "layoutManager.scrollToPositionWithOffset(0, 0);"

Comment: if you have layoutmanager reference you can directly call the above method with layoutmanager reference

Comment: Ok I used the reference.  The app ran but no scrolling occurred, not sure why.

Comment: you should add those lines after the `add()` method called

Comment: how can it scroll to begining if you call that even before seting adapter

Comment: well I had it set below the Adapter as well with no luck.

Comment: man you have to call it after your `add()` method called i.e., after you insert a item successfully you call

Comment: Ok so does that mean I need to move the Runnable() into the Adapter after add()?

Comment: yeah only after you add elements if you call those lines it will work

Comment: Tried it in the Adapter.  App crashes.  It doesn't like the Runnable line and then it doesn't like the addAll() line.  So maybe I need to move to after addAll()?

Comment: how did you get layout manger and recycleview reference inside adapter

Comment: I've run out of time to try to fix this issue.  I will try again tomorrow...thanks for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

I use this with a "scroll to top" button, you can try work your way around with it :

```
LinearLayoutManager mlayoutManager = (LinearLayoutManager) rv.getLayoutManager();
    mlayoutManager.scrollToPositionWithOffset(0, 0);
```

Comment: Ok I will give it a try.

Comment: No luck.  I don't get any scrolling at all.